# Верстка таблицы

Tags: php, html, css

Нужно создание подобие такой вот таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные берутся из базы. Проблема в том, что даже нет идеи как это сделать. Не знаю за что взяться и с чего начать. Если бы я просто рисовал таблицу вручную с помощью [html](/questions/tagged/html) (каждую ячейку), кажется, было бы куда легче. Прописал бы стили в [css](/questions/tagged/css) и дело в шляпе. Но я вытаскиваю записи из базы с помощью такого вот кода:

```
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
      print '<table><tr>';
      foreach ($row as $name => $value){
        print "<th>$name</th>";
      }
      while($row){
        print '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value){
          print "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        print '<tr>';
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
      }
      print '</table>';
```

Получается это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не прошу писать за меня код. А хотя бы дать какой-то толчок и направление. Возможно нужно как-то по другому вытаскивать данные, либо рисовать таблицу вручную? Потому что конкретно сейчас я никак не могу разделить ячейки, есть только [table](/questions/tagged/table), [th](/questions/tagged/th), [tr](/questions/tagged/tr), [td](/questions/tagged/td). То есть в [css](/questions/tagged/css) могу делать изменения только для всего вместе, а не для каждого элемента в отдельности. Извиняюсь, если вопрос тупой. Очень надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Какая разница откуда берутся данные? Это уже клиентская сторона. Да и не совсем понятно, ты что хочешь? Сделать фильтрацию полей, удаление/редактирование и т.д и т.п.? Тогда в чем проблема, изучай `javascript`, как работает паджинация. Можно сказать ты делаешь DataGrid, которых кстати не так и мало. Посмотри готовые примеры, может не нужно будет городить свой велосипед

Comment: Да пока без функционала, просто сверстать такую таблицу. Просто если бы я рисовал каждую ячейку вручную, я мог бы указывать для каждой свои стили. А так как у меня таблица генерируется с помощью php - я не могу понять как привести ее в красивый вид. Ибо если буду редактировать, допустим, стили для td, то они они будут применяться ко всем td в table,а не к каким-то конкретным.

Comment: Ну как так... Вы не знаете что такое `CSS`? Не играет абсолютно никакой откуда берутся данные, стили создаете и все работает

Comment: Зачем вам в таблице нужно конкретную ячейку менять? Строки же принципиально одинаковы, нет? Значит у каждой строки есть какой-то шаблон, в которой вы можете задать стили, а потом по этому шаблону и отрисовать все строки.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и создайте таблицу вручную, пропишите css. Когда все будет готово, выберите данные из бд в массив, а потом с помощью foreach выводите данные

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($rows as $row):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$row['column']?></td>
    ..........
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

И прекратите использовать mysql_* функции. Есть же замечательный PDO, mysqli